# Problems in pl/sql using case in a repetitive structure

Tags: oracle, plsql

My exercise ask me to loop all the clients from my table and show those which have a discount > 0.1. For according the discount i need to use case.
The cod displays me no data found. If i replace c.id_client=1 instead of c.id_client=id_min, it works, but i don't want this.
The code:

```
Declare
  v_nume clienti_sebi.nume %type;
  v_prenume clienti_sebi.prenume %type;
  v_count number;
  v_discount number;
  id_min clienti_sebi.id_client %type;
  id_max clienti_sebi.id_client %type;
Begin

  select min(id_client), max(id_client) into id_min, id_max from clienti_sebi;

  while id_min<id_max
  loop

    select c.nume, c.prenume, count(p.nr_polita)numar_polite,
           (case
            when count(p.nr_polita)=1 then 0.1
            when count(p.nr_polita)=2 then 0.2
            else 0.3 end) DC
    into v_nume, v_prenume, v_count, v_discount
    from clienti_sebi c, polita p
    where c.id_client=p.id_client and c.id_client=id_min
    group by c.nume, c.prenume;

    dbms_output.put_line(id_min);

    if v_discount > 0.1 then
      dbms_output.put_line(v_nume || ' ' || v_prenume || ' ' || v_count || ' ' || v_discount);
    else null;
    end if;

    id_min:=id_min+1;

  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently assumes that there are no gaps in your `id_client` sequence. This is an unnecessary assumption and your code could be made much simpler by looping over your query, instead of getting the min/max values, e.g.:

```
for r in (
  select c.nume, c.prenume, count(p.nr_polita) numar_polite,
         (case
          when count(p.nr_polita)=1 then 0.1
          when count(p.nr_polita)=2 then 0.2
          else 0.3 end) discount
  from clienti_sebi c, polita p
  group by c.nume, c.prenume
  ) loop

  if r.discount > 0.1 then
    dbms_output.put_line(r.nume || ' ' || r.prenume || ' ' || r.numar_polite || ' ' || r.discount);
  end if;

end loop;
```

You could also use the `HAVING` clause to avoid having to check your condition within the loop:

```
for r in (
  select c.nume, c.prenume, count(p.nr_polita) numar_polite,
         (case
          when count(p.nr_polita)=1 then 0.1
          when count(p.nr_polita)=2 then 0.2
          else 0.3 end) discount
  from clienti_sebi c, polita p
  group by c.nume, c.prenume
  having count(p.nr_polita) > 1
  ) loop

  dbms_output.put_line(r.nume || ' ' || r.prenume || ' ' || r.count || ' ' || r.discount);

end loop;
```